# What is best way to connect data from different services and use them with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angular-ngmodel, angular-services

I'm new to angular and to design some complicated things...

I have two services: `phrasesService` and `translationsService`, they store two objects:

```
phrases = [{text: "phrase1"}, {text: "phrase2"}, {text: "phrase3"}]        
translations = [{ language: "russian", phrases: ["phrase1", "phrase2", "phrase3"] }, {language: "hindi", phrases: ["phrase1", "phrase2", "phrase3"]}]
```

And I have methods to get translations:

`getTranslationsInLang(lang)` that returns array of phrases in lang
and 
`getPhraseTranslation(lang, numPhrase)` that returns translation of one phrase

Now I want to display phrases and their translations in inputs (for editing):

```
<input class="form-control phrase-text" type="text" ng-model="phrase.text">
<input class="form-control translation-text" type="text" ng-model="????.translation">
```

1. What is the best way to realize this, for store all data and display it for editing?
2. And what should I use in ng-model for translation input?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your data structure is not optimal. What you seem to want is to have a data structure which is capable of returning the relevant translation phrase for a tuple of the original phrase and the translation language.

Consider using something like this:

`originals = {id: phrase, ...}
translations = {language_id: {id: phrase_translation, ...}, ...}`

Thus, having `current_phrase_id` and `current_language_id` you'll it will be easy to access the translation.